# auto uploading from openshift rhc to github?

Tags: git, bash, github, openshift

I need to one bash code witch automatically upload one folder to github.com site from Openshift RHC Servers.

So i added the SSH key of openshift RHC to Github successfully. and i could insert one folder entire to Github server manually by this codes:

```
echo "# openshift-test23" >> README2.md
git init
#git add README2.md
git add .
git config --global user.name "soheilpaper"
#git config --global user.email soheil_paper@yahoo.com
#git commit --amend --reset-author
git commit -a  -m "first commit"
git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': xyz
Password for 'https://xyz@github.com':
```

but when i want to write one code to automatically upload one folder to Github from Openshift RHC, need to manually enter username and password by this codes:

```
$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': xyz
Password for 'https://xyz@github.com':
```

so how could i bypass it in openshift RHC Linux servers?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by this codes:

```
    echo "# openshift-test23" >> README2.md
    git init

    #git add README2.md
    git add .
   git config remote.origin.url https://Username:password@github.com/Username/openshift-test
     #git commit --amend --reset-author
    git commit -a  -m "first commit"


    git remote add origin https://github.com/xxx/openshift-test.git
    git config remote.origin.url https://Username:password@github.com//openshift-test

    git push -u origin master
```